# How to find array of months from current month with a step of x months

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I want to generate an array of months such that it contains the current month and all months after a particular gap.

For example, `Find 3 months steps from the current month in a year.`

Something like:

```
def months_from(offset:, current_month)
...
end
```

So, for `months_from(offset: 3.months, current_month: 8) it gives [8, 11, 2, 5]`

and for `months_from(offset: 6.months, current_month: 8) it gives [8, 2]`
and soo on.

How can I write `months_from` method? Is there something in ruby/rails to achieve this?

Comment: How many results is it supposed to return?  Why does the first example return 4 months while the second example returns 2 months?

Comment: judging from the question, he wanted the range in between a year. that's why the first example returns 4 months because the offset is 3 months each

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ruby [Date](https://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-3.0.2/libdoc/date/rdoc/Date.html) class has the .next_month(integer) method that will automatically add several months from your provided date. So for your question, it can be done like this:

```
def months_from(offset, current_month)
    result = [current_month]
    loop = 12/offset # we need to find how many times is the steps in a year

    (1...loop).each do |index|
        result << Date.strptime(current_month.to_s, '%m').next_month(offset*index).strftime('%m').to_i
        
    end

    result
end
```